# Iterating over first 5 elements in Knockout.JS using foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I can iterate over all elements using this code

```
<!-- ko foreach: tweets -->
        <input  style="width: 200px" data-bind="value: tweet"/>
        <a  class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.queueSubmit" >
            Send
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-bind = "click: $parent.removeTweet" >
            Delete
        </a>

       </br>

     <!-- /ko -->
```

How can I change it to limit it to display only the first 5 tweets?  Unable to find documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing a `tweets.slice(0, 5)` will give you the first five.

You could consider putting this in a computed on your view model like:

```
this.numberToShow = 5;

this.tweetsFiltered = ko.computed(function() {
    return tweets.slice(0, this.numberToShow);
}, this);
```